# WSO2 Tenant Restful API as an alternative to SOAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I experimented with Tenant API https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/92523614 which is using SOAP, is there REST alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Tenant management REST API [1] available in WSO2 IS 5.11.0 version (latest release), but not in the previuos versions.

[1] https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/tenant-management-rest-api/

Comment: One more question, how can I install WSO2 IS 5.11.0 from Docker? I am executing "docker run -it -p 9443:9443 docker.wso2.com/wso2is -DosgiConsole", but in logs I see "CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0"

Comment: Another question, I installed version 5.11.0 (from zip file), but can't see new console as shown here https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.11.0

Comment: IS-5.11.0 docker image is not yet available in https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/wso2is/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated. New portal is accessible via https://localhost:9443/console. The legacy portal(carbon console) is accessible via https://localhost:9443/carbon/

Answer (score 0):

For the question related to docker. I built a docker of wso2is 5.11.0 thanks to https://github.com/wso2/docker-is. Then I set the deployment.toml file with my own settings. Once running, I recommend to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162) to complete a basic installation.