# Myaccount and Console apps in WSO2IS-5.11.0 are not working when the server started with port offset

Tags: authentication, callback, openid-connect, wso2-identity-server

Changing the port by changing the offset in the *deployment.toml* or using `-DportOffset` doesn't get applied to the Console and the My Account applications.

**How to reproduce:**

1. Change the offset by adding the following config to the deployment.toml

```
[server]
offset=2
```

2. Start the server
3. Access the console app from https://localhost:9445/console
4. Access the my account app from https://localhost:9445/myaccount

Following error is displayed.

[image]

Observed, that the reason is that the callback URL is not changed when the hostname or port is changed. Even changing the URLs manually from the management console is not allowed.

What is the recommendation to get Myaccount and Console apps working when hostname or port is changed?

Answer (score 3):

An approach is to manually change the callback URL of the Myaccount and Console apps accordingly when a port or hostname change is done in the server, by removing these applications from the system applications list.

Steps:

1. Change hostname or port of the server
2. Remove Myaccount and Console apps from read only system apps by adding the following to the deployment.toml

   ```
    [system_applications]
    read_only_apps = []
   ```
3. Restart the server
4. Update callback URL of the myaccount and console apps from the management console accordingly.
5. Change the issuer URI of the Resident IDP accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

These applications can be hosted externally. In that case the callback URLs can have different hostnames and ports.

Thus, it is not good to change the callback URLs automatically. So, the manual option is [Aysh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6720383/aysh) pointed in the above comment is the recommended approach ATM.