# WSO2IS 5.11.0 - Blank screen when accessing to /myaccount or /console web page

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I deployed to test the last release of WSO2 5.11.0 in Docker container. I did not change anything in the default configuration except the hostname and callbackURL for the "Console" and "My Account" service providers to match my hostname.

Access to the carbon console is fine. But when I try to reach `https://<hostname>/console` or `https://<hostname>/myaccount`, I can fill my login and password, then I have a blank page without anything.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Follow the steps in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162. You should have missed step(5). Change : Resident IDP> Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration >Identity Provider Entity ID

Comment: Thank you very much Anuradha. I did all step except the one to "5. Change the issuer URI of the Resident IDP accordingly from your link" . Now it is OK. Do you think there is a way to set these value in deployment.toml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the answer from comments:

If you change the host/port of the server **after one fresh pack startup**, you have to follow the steps in [stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162) manually. On the other hand, if you change the host/port before the fresh IS pack server startup these changes applied automatically.

Out of the steps in [stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162](http://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162),
You should **have missed step 5** which causes you to see a blank page.
Navigate to : Resident IDP > Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration  and change **Identity Provider Entity ID** accordingly.

Further, these value changes can't be done via deployment.toml.

Comment: Thank you very much Anuradha. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue, upon initial startup with what I believe is a correct configuration:

When adding an HTTPS [ProxyPort](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/deployment-guide/#clustering-related-configurations) config of 443

```
[server]
hostname = "identity.myorg.io"
...
[transport.https.properties]
proxyPort = 443
```

Upon initial startup, the Resident IdP erroneously sets the `Identity Provider Entity ID` to `https://identity.myorg.io:443/oauth2/token`.

This means that when accessing -> `https://identity.myorg.io/console|myaccount` the same issue as described by the OP is encountered.

Manually changing the IDP EID to remove the `:443` fixes it. The server should do this automatically for port 443.

Comment: Identity Server version `5.11.0.181`