# After user login, myaccount hangs on "loading" a blank page

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

When a user tries to login into myaccount, a blank screen will be displayed.

We had the problem on WSO2-IS - 5.11.0, it continues to exist on WSO2-IS 6.0.0
With the same user, some days there are no problems, but there are days when the myaccount is hanging consistently. And it happens to any user, just there is no pattern.
Even if the browser is changed, restarted, browsing history deleted, incognito - does not help.
myaccount is on the same system with WSO2IS, ntp is active. Httpd proxy in front of the IS, port 443. As mentioned before, the login in most cases works.
What was tried:

- Everything from the related thread https://discord.com/channels/955510916064092180/1121435919124279307/1121435919124279307 is still the same.
- Checked all ramifications from https://discord.com/channels/955510916064092180/1137989356225826827/1139355691522473994 , no effect
- Also from the recommended https://discord.com/channels/955510916064092180/1137989356225826827/1137992360404471839, all the steps, no change
- And followed the steps from here [WSO2IS 5.11.0 - Blank screen when accessing to /myaccount or /console web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65372975/wso2is-5-11-0-blank-screen-when-accessing-to-myaccount-or-console-web-page) but that did not help

I see also a difference that was noticed between the working case and non-working case:  - in the non-working case there are two POST requests for token

By activating the scim2 debug in log4j2.properties, we see that after the jwks verification, there is no request to scim2 /Me endpoint or anything on scim2, the log just stops, no error, nothing.

By activating in deployment.toml the oauth logger:

```
 [event.default_listener.oauth_listener] 
  priority= 12
  enable = true
```

In transaction.log we have only two lines:

```
[2023-10-11 13:23:24,771] - Type: OAUTH TOKEN | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"time_taken_in_millis":173,"type":"oauth","issued_time":1697030604662,"user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"} 
[2023-10-11 13:23:28,088] - Type: OAUTH TOKEN | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3596,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"time_taken_in_millis":99,"type":"oauth","issued_time":1697030604662,"user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
```

whether in the functioning case, we have one line with Type: OAUTH TOKEN and five lines with Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION

```
[2023-10-11 16:06:06,024] - Type: OAUTH TOKEN | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"time_taken_in_millis":37,"type":"oauth","issued_time":1697029566001,"user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:06,347] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":5,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:06,809] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":3,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:06,913] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":2,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:06,964] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3600,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":2,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:07,286] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3599,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":3,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
[2023-10-11 16:06:07,319] - Type: OAUTH INTROSPECTION | Info: {"expires_in_seconds":3599,"grant_type":"authorization_code","success":true,"scope":"internal_login openid","time_taken_in_millis":2,"issued_time":1697029566,"type":"introspection","user":"username@test.com@carbon.super","client_id":"MY_ACCOUNT"}
```

Is there a solution for this? Or where else can we check to help us fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are we sure this is only observed for the my account application? Since my account is also an SP within tenant, the similar behaviour could be observed for console as well

Comment: Hi @GoushiRam, you are right. We observe the same behavior for the console app as well.