# How to enable the new & beta GUI of WSO2 IS version 5.11.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've installed the new `WSO2 IS (Version 5.11.0)` on Debian 10.7 but regardless of their release notes that mention about new GUI based on React, the console interface is like the previous version (`5.10.0`).

How can I enable the new GUI for the console web application?

Answer (score 1):

The new console can be accessed via - `https://<host>:<port>/console`

The old console can be accessed via -  `https://<host>:<port>/carbon`

The new my account portal can be accessed via - `https://<host>:<port>/myaccount`

Also, these links are logged in the carbon logs once the server starts up.

Comment: Thanks Anuradha,
But after entering to address https://<myhost.ourdomain>:9443/console it says:
"Registered callback does not match with the provided url. "

Based on WSO2 documentation, I tried to change it via the old Carbon GUI:
Identity -> Service Providers -> List -> Console -> Edit -> Inbound Authentication Configuration -> OAuth/OIDC Configuration -> Edit -> Callback Url

Change it from "localhost" to "<myhost.ourdomain>",  and hit "update" key.

But it open a dialog and says: "Error occurred while updating the application"

Any clue?

Comment: Since you have changed the hostname you should have followed these steps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162) to update the callback URL etc. Go through this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/65387053/10055162