# WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-5.11.0) - Blank page after logging in to the console

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2is-5.11.0 and a blank page appears in once I enter my login credentials and hit on login. In the browser console, the following could be seen.
"Uncaught (in promise) Invalid id_token in the token response"

[image: Invalid id_token]

The resident IdP URLs are set properly as well, using the current hostname.
A valid solution to resolve this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the host/port of the Identity Server **after one fresh pack startup**, you have to follow the steps in  this Stack Overflow answe http://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162 manually. On the other hand, if you change the host/port before the fresh Identity Server pack server startup, these changes applied automatically.

Out of the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/a/65353673/10055162, You may have missed step 5, which can lead to a blank page. To address this issue, navigate to : **Resident IDP > Inbound Authentication Configuration > OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration** and change *Identity Provider Entity ID* accordingly.

Further, these value changes can't be done via deployment.toml.

Please refer these for more information[1][2].

[1]https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/12420

[2][WSO2IS 5.11.0 - Blank screen when accessing to /myaccount or /console web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65372975/wso2is-5-11-0-blank-screen-when-accessing-to-myaccount-or-console-web-page?rq=2)